# How to embed one page into another while keeping it responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `page-container.html` and I would like to embed `page-embeddable.html` into it.  On its own `page-embeddable.html` is responsive (it's height changes based on width of containing element) and I want to keep that characteristic when I embed it.

I've the following methods without much success:

1. `iframe` tag.  It just isn't responsive.  It only works if the height of `page-embeddable.html` is fixed.  But it isn't - it reflows itself and the height is dynamic.
2. `object` tag.  I tried setting `<object type="text/html" data="page-embeddable.html"></object>` to `innerHtml` of an element, but it acts pretty much acts as an iframe.  Not responsive.
3. Cut up `page-embeddable.html` into pieces.  Load whatever .js and .css the page references via JavaScript.  Then load the insides of the body tag into the .innerHtml of some div on `page-container.html`.  This works and is responsive and the height is dynamic, but `page-embeddable.html` is dynamically generated and could have different js/css references based on context.  So I'd have to work out what's in the file prior to loading it.

Is there a better way to embed a page that I am overlooking?
For context, I am trying to deliver an embedded widget, kind of like [Codepen](https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/), except the height needs to be dynamic.

Comment: instead of trying to do it on the front-end, generate the entire page on the backend by using a templating solution? That way the client just gets "a normal html document" instead of something that tries to include an entire second document.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The client should be able to embed the widget into any page.  Client being a customer that buys access my widget.  So I can't deliver him a full page.  I basically provide the client a foo.js from my site and a .load(elementIdToRenderTheWidgetOn) method.

Comment: You want to look into  embedding a [web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) who's resources and styles won't conflict with parent page

Comment: @charlietfl Support seems like of sketchy.  https://caniuse.com/#search=components

Comment: Haven't worked with them a lot but I believe there are some fallback approaches. Was just throwing it out there